# How do i slice an string?

Tags: javascript, string, slice

How do i slice an string in javascript?
Like `let name="my name is sebok das"`
To `name="sebok"`
Result `console.log(name)= my name is sebok`

Comment: `'my name is sobek das'.slice(0, -4)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in functions like .splitOnLast and then append .at().

`let newName = name.splitOnLast(' ').at(0)`

This splits the string into `['my name is sebok', 'das']` and then points to the element at index 0.

`console.log(newName)` will print `'my name is sebok'`. Try to use these methods to achieve printing just `'sebok'`. Hint: `.split()` also exists.

For more information about built-in methods for string manipulation, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String